# Simplest MySQL to MySQLi transition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently using the depreciated MySQL that I've been taught in a class. I saw that it's not the right way to go and there are two better options: MySQLi and, even better, PDO. While I find switching to PDO to be kinda difficult for me since I have no idea whatsoever about OOP, I think that switching to at least MySQLi is a must. I checked SO and other sources in advance of this question for information regarding the transition and I tried to apply what I learned but it didn't ended up too well so I'll just post my current connection to the database and wait for a MySQLi transition of this code. If it comes with explanations that's even better, since learning is my purpose, not just using the code. If not... I'll try to figure it out by myself, having the correct code in front of my eyes and the old code will show me what's different.

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER","root");
    define("DB_PASS", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE","spore_db");

    $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Please let me know before downrating so I can edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: What a nice question :) +1

Comment: You should at least have a go yourself, post some code and if you need any further help then come back here.

Comment: ok all there is in this example is `$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_DATABASE) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect));`

Comment: I had a go but I encountered problems after problems and instead of posting them here so that you can fix them one by one while I am clueless to what happens because of what, I picked the road that helps not only me but other users as well see how a very simple mysqli_connect should look like. I'll reproduce it, not copy paste it, that's a promise. I recommend for the others to do the same.

Comment: @Dexa What would $link be?

Comment: it would be copy/past :) instead of $link use $connect. Fixed now, thank you

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and now when I run a query I get the following warnings: 
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\includes\db_connect.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\includes\db_connect.php on line 9

Comment: Line 9 is mysqli_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: you specify database as 4th parameter in my 1st comment, line 9 is not needed. Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Thank you Dexa. That worked alright, the errors that I now get are because of the content of another .php file. I'll check the new functions and if I don't get it right I'll post another question with the contents of that file. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

1. This is not a nice question by any means. **Stack overflow is not a place to ask for a tutorial at all.**
2. Instead of asking for a tutorial you have to google for one, then try, then ask a question on a particular problem you stuck with.
3. Replacing `mysql_` functions with their `mysqli_` counterparts mechanically **makes absolutely no sense**
4. **What you really need** is to get rid of calling RAW API functions, be it mysqli or mysql, right in the application code. And start using some sort of abstraction library instead. Especially because **with working with raw mysqli is just awful experience**
5. PDO is better than mysqli only because it is being such a library itself.
6. OOP is not that scary in terms of using it. Nobody asks you to write your own OOP code, while calling existing OOP methods is no more complex than calling familiar functions. The only difference is `->` thing:

   ```
   $result = function($data);
   $result = $class->function($data);
   ```

   This is **ALL** you need to know about OOP to use it (save for the variable scope issues)

[To try PDO out](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) is not that complex as you imagine. You'd have to start learn programming some day - so, it's better to start sooner.

Comment: I understand that SO is not a tutorial website however everybody seems to say "don't use MySQL, use MySQLi or PDO instead" and point to different questions that didn't helped me not to a good tutorial. And if SO isn't a tutorial website what is it? A "fix my problem cause I forgot the comma and I get this error" website? I think that by this question you can help a ton of people to switch from MySQL to MySQLi and if I find a complete solution I'll post the answer myself so that I can help them. It doesn't hurt me to hand over a few lines of code that is by no means complex if you know it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not taking it personally. I'm just pointing my point of view while finding your post helpful regarding the PDO part.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are already a thousand questions on the topic. If you can't find one - it's your fault.

Comment: Honestly, your problem with mysql_select_db *IS* the forgotten comma kind. And your demands are like "I don't want to read no manual page - so, write me one here in place"

Comment: Not really. My demands are like: I want to learn, I'll go to the manual, but having a complete working script in front of my eyes would help me very much. As I said, I don't need the script just to use it, I could ask a experienced web developer to write one for me if that was the case (not on SO) and he wouldn't be so mad about his 2 mins spent to help. The reason why I asked here is that I think I'm helping others as well, not only myself. Keep in mind that everybody has his own learning rythm and methods.

Comment: Ok, I've seen such a selfish behavior too many times to make it worth any further conversation.

Comment: Well said @SporeDev. :-) If you look at Your Common Sense profile you will see less than 2.5K up-votes but more than 12.5k down-votes. Hope you can understand what he's doing here. Plus according to my knowledge he was banned once too. :-)

Comment: The only reason that I engaged in this conversation was that he provided some information about PDO (even if that was not my question, the more information the merrier). I'll keep linking this question when I ask something on SO and get the "switch to MySQLi or PDO" remarks until it gets solved unless I solve it myself. I'm glad someone shares my opinion, it means that my question is not pointless or too localized. Cheers!