# Getting the value from MySQL to check radio buttons generates a notice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set the "checked" status of a radio button based on the value from the MySQL database. The main purpose of the code is to be a "edit user profile data" script. I managed to get all information from the database and everything gets edited as it should if the user choses to but I can't seem to make the radio buttons work. I get the following message:

Notice: Use of undefined constant Male - assumed 'Male' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\user_panel.php on line 57

I checked SO for this notice but I couldn't find anything related to radio buttons AND the notice.

This is the code:

```
<form action="includes/user_panel.php" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email"> E-mail </label></td>
                        <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo "{$fetch['email']}"; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="first_name"> First name </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo "{$fetch['first_name']}"; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="last_name"> Last name </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo "{$fetch['last_name']}"; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="birthday"> Birthday </label></td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" value="<?php echo "{$fetch['birthday']}"; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="sex"> Sex </label></td>
                        <?php
                        if ($fetch['sex'] = male)
                        {
                            echo "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' id='sex' checked> Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' id='sex'> Female </td>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' id='sex'> Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' id='sex' checked> Female </td>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                <input type="submit" name="edit_user" value="Edit" class="button_1">
                <input type="hidden" name="edit_user_data">
            </form>
```

Additional information:

```
$initial_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query_user_panel="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$initial_email' OR username= '$username'";
$result_user_panel=mysql_query($query_user_panel) or die (mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_user_panel)
```

Line 57 is the one with the "if".

Scroll down the code and you'll see where the sex should get checked. I tried with a "if" but that generates me the notice that I wrote.

I know that MySQL is depreciated and I should use MySQLi. If you have the time please check this question as well: [Simplest MySQL to MySQLi transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782831/simplest-mysql-to-mysqli-transition)

Thank you very much and please let me know if I need to edit my post or provide with additional data.

Comment: You should use == instead of = to compare in the if.

Comment: How is the sex stored in the database? Why is it stored in a column named birthday?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my code. That was an error. Thank you for paying attention to it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have to forgot to put == instead of = as well as you have to put Male in quotes.

It should look like this:

```
if ($fetch['birthday'] == "Male")
```

Also, are you sure that birthday field is correct one to check for sex?

Comment: :)) Thank you for noticing that I typed "birthday" instead of "sex". I no longer get the Notice. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. I'll also edit the question so that others don't get confused. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I found there are three mistakes

1) `$fetch['birthday']`, I think it should be another field name like sex

2) `if ($fetch['birthday'] = Male)`, `=` should be `==` so, `if ($fetch['birthday'] == "Male")`

3) `if ($fetch['birthday'] == "Male")`, you missed double quotes for string so should be "Male"

```
<?php

    if ($fetch['birthday'] == "Male")
    {
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' id='sex' checked> Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' id='sex'> Female </td>";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' id='sex'> Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' id='sex' checked> Female </td>";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that he can check without quotes without defining a global variable?

Comment: I find your answer as useful as the one that I'm about to accept (because he answered first) and that's why I'm upvoting it. I edited my code so that it won't confuse others. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this
if ($fetch['sex'] == 'Male')

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted a solution where when data is pulled from the database to edit a form, if the account is "**Active**" it will check the "**Active**" radio button and if the account is "**Inactive**" it will check the **Inactive** radio button on the html form.
I have used tinyint in the mysql database using: 1 - **Active** and 0 - **Inactive**
The code i have used that does this successfully is below:

```
<label for="Active">Active</label>
<input id="Active" type="radio" name="Active" value="1"<?php if ($row['Active'] == 1): ?> checked = "checked"<?php endif; ?> />

<label for="Active">Inactive</label>
<input id="Active" type="radio" name="Active" value="0"<?php if ($row['Active'] != 1): ?> checked = "checked"<?php endif; ?> />
```

So when i query a record and it has a value of '**1**' in the database field then the **Active** radio button will be filled and the **Inactive** button empty and when i query a record and it has a value of '**0**' in the database field then the **Inactive** radio button will be filled and the **Active** button empty.

Hope this helps