# dynamic generated page changes its link when a submit button is being pressed

Tags: php, mysql

I have an advertising website project where users can add their offers for different tourism related businesses. I created the dynamic generated page for each offer and I would like to add a comment box to it where visitors can post their opinions. The page is generated as it should, the link being advertisement.php?id=2 where the id is the id of that offer. When I click the submit button for the comment the page link changes to advertisement.php?advertisement_comment=&place_comment=Place+comment where advertisement_comment is the name of the comment box and place_comment is the name of the submit button. Because of this I get Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\advertisement.php on line 3. My id variable is equal to $_GET['id'] but since the page url changes it can no longer get it. Is there any way I can prevent the link from changing? If not maybe you can think of a different database structure and php code that I can use to get where I want because I'm kinda stuck. Please let me know if I need to edit my question in any way before downrating. Thank you very much!

Code for the generated page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    require_once("includes/db_connect.php");


    $query_dynamic_advertisement = "SELECT * FROM advertisings WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result_dynamic_advertisement = mysql_query($query_dynamic_advertisement) or die (mysql_error());
    $fetch_dynamic_advertisement = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_dynamic_advertisement);

    // Hit counter
    $query_advertising_views="UPDATE advertisings SET advertising_views = advertising_views + 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result_advertising_views=mysql_query($query_advertising_views) or die (mysql_error());

    // Comments
    if (isset($_POST['place_comment']))
    {
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[advertisement_comment]);
        $advertising_id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $query_place_comment = "INSERT INTO advertising_comments VALUES ('', '$comment', '$advertising_id')";
        mysql_query($query_place_comment) or die (mysql_error());       
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            </br>
            <a href="index.php"><h3>Home</h3></a>
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="SporeDEV logo" id="logo"></a>
            </br>
            <!-- Meniu -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="includes/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="advertising_panel.php">Advertising Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="user_panel.php">User Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="user_profile.php">User Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="admin_panel.php">Admin Panel</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sfarsit de meniu -->
            </br>
            <?php
                echo "<p> General information </p>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Location name: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['location_name']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Location type: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['location_type']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "<p> Address </p>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Region: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['region']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Settlement: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['settlement']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Street: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['street']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Street number: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['street_number']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "<p> Contact information </p>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "E-mail: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['email']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Phone: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['phone']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Website: <a href={$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['website']} target=_blank>{$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['website']}</a>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "<p> Statistics </p>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Added: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['add_date']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Modified: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['last_modified']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Advertising views: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['advertising_views']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "<p> Description </p>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Description: {$fetch_dynamic_advertisement['description']}";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                echo "<p> Comments </p>";
                echo "</br>";
            ?>  
                <!-- Comment form -->
                <p> Add a comment </p>
                </br>
                <form action = "advertisement.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method = "$_POST">
                    <textarea name="advertisement_comment"></textarea>
                    </br>
                    <input type="submit" name="place_comment" class="button_1" value="Place comment">
                </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The structure of the table advertising_comments is: id(int 11, autoincrement), comment (varchar 255), advertising_id (int 11, this should be the same as the id of the initial page).

I know that MySQL is depreciated. If you have the time please check this question as well: [Simplest MySQL to MySQLi transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782831/simplest-mysql-to-mysqli-transition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is changing following the form submission because it's defaulting to the GET method. This is due to a typo in your form element.

Change this line:

```
<form action = "advertisement.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method = "$_POST">
```

to:

```
<form action="advertisement.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">
```

This will allow your comment form to be submitted using POST.

Extra note, you should sanitize the **all** the user inputs, including the page ID to prevent SQL injection attacks. This is not safe:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. After I solved that I got another error because my $advertisement_comment was wrong, not quoting the key. How should I sanitize $id? html_special_chars is ok (since I use MySQL not MySQLi)?

Comment: I don't think html_special_chars will completely protect you from malicious SQL - you need to escape the strings with functions like mysql_real_escape_string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). If your ID is numeric you could typecast the variable as an int value. Like `$id = (int) $_GET['id'] `

Comment: Yes, I did that and it works, I was fearing that it will no longer work if I use mysql_real_escape_string but that's not the case. Thank you very much, I didn't knew that I should sanitize variables that go in the url as well, I knew just about the ones from the inputs.